# Data Migration / Copy from Unix to AS400 QSH

Tags: perl, unix, ibm-midrange

Usually we run regression on UNIX box and the same regression is run on AS400 QSh box.

On UNIX suppose we have the folder structure as /home/qa/regression/Folder1 or 2 or 3 or 4 and so on.

The same structure is present on AS400 QSH box i.e /home/qa/regression/Folder1 or 2 or 3 or 4 and so on.

Here what I want is suppose I have added one file in UNIX box in each folder the same file i need on the AS400 QSh box. (Here the solution would be that I can link the folders but take a lot of time while running regression so have made a copy on both the boxes). Right now we have more 1000 folders in which a new file is added we want that file in the AS400 QSH box copying it one by one will take lot of time.

So can any one have me with writing and Perl script of copying data from one box to another.

Note : The folder names are identical for both the boxes.

Comment: Please Can any one help with the code.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be - don't use perl. `rsync` is an excellent tool for this job.

If you really must go for a perlish solution, you probably want to consider `File::Find`.

Comment: It's true that rsync is pretty much the ideal tool for this job; that's what it was created to do. Just be aware that it's not necessarily present on the IBM midrange (IBM i, iSeries, AS/400). Google "rsync for pase" for more information.

Comment: Can you help me with the script or code we need for this. or can you be more specific whats the use of rsync.Also just for one confirmation my regression is on UNIX box and same is setup on QSH (Its a copy not a Link) will rsync will sync that

Comment: http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html - yes, rsync will sync that. `rsync -avz /source/path remote_client:/remote/path`